# Homotopy factorization of morphisms of chain complexes

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory

This is a sort of follow up to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165825/postnikov-towers-in-bounded-t-structures).

Let $R$ be a ring (eventually with good properties) and $\mathrm{Chains}(R)$ be the category of chain complexes of $R$-modules (eventually bounded). One has the natural endofunctors $\tau_{\leq n}$ and $\tau_{\geq n}$ associated with the standard t-structure on $\mathrm{Chains}(R)$.

What I'm wondering is the following. Is it true that for every morphism $f\colon A\to B$ of chain complexes there exist morphisms $h:A\to C$ and $g:C\to B$ with $\tau_{\leq -1}(h)\colon \tau_{\leq -1}(A)\to \tau_{\leq -1}(C)$ a weak equivalence (in the standard model structure on chain complexes), $\tau_{\geq 0}(g)\colon \tau_{\geq 0}(C)\to \tau_{\geq 0}(B)$ a weak equivalence, and with $f$ homotopy equivalent to $g\circ h$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the following diagram in which the rows are cofiber sequences:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\tau_{\geq0}A @>>> A @>>> \tau_{\leq-1}A @>>>\Sigma\tau_{\geq0}A\\
@VVV @VVV @| @VVV\\
\tau_{\geq0}B @>>> C @>>> \tau_{\leq-1}A @>>>\Sigma\tau_{\geq0}B\\
@| @VVV @VVV @|\\
\tau_{\geq0}B @>>> B @>>> \tau_{\leq-1}B @>>>\Sigma\tau_{\geq0}B
\end{CD}$$

Here the vertical maps in the first, third, and fourth columns are the maps induced by $f$, and $C$ can be obtained as the fiber of the rightmost map in the middle row.  The second column is then the factorization you seek.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks! Indeed my candidate for $C$ was $C=\tau_{\leq -1}A\times_{\tau_{\leq-1}B}B$, which I see is the same $C$ you get, but I had been unable to show that $A\to C$ and $C\to B$ became equivalences under $\tau_{\leq -1}$ and $\tau_{\geq 0}$ by the fiber product description. Now I see how looking at the pullback diagram as a part of  the big diagram gives that immediately by using $\tau_{\leq -1}\tau_{\geq 0}=0$ and $\tau_{\leq -1}\Sigma\tau_{\geq 0}=0$ and the 3-for-2 property for equivalences. And it also works for an arbitrary t-structure on a triangulated category, right?

Comment: Actually, if I'm not mistaken, there is a subtlety that prevents my construction from working for an arbitrary triangulated category with t-structure.  Namely, you cannot be sure that the composition $A\to C\to B$ is equal to the original map; all you know is that it is _some_ map that commutes with the top and bottom cofiber sequences (but such maps are not unique).  What you need is that everything lifts to an $\infty$-category in which the sequences $\tau_{\geq0}A\to A\to\tau_{\leq-1}A$ are functorial and there is also a functorial nullhomotopy of the composition.

Comment: The functoriality of the nullhomotopy makes all the choices of maps in the second column canonical and functorial.

Comment: Perfect! a stable $\infty$-category with functorial truncation sequences and nullhomotopies was precisely the context I had in mind! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to imply that was any sort of harsh restriction.  I don't know of any "natural" examples that don't satisfy that.

Comment: I'm having some trouble in verifying that this defines a true factorization system on $\text{Ch}(R)$. In a few words it seems that your procedure defined a factorization functor $F\colon f\mapsto (f_L, f_R)$. But now do $\mathcal E = \{f\mid f_R\text{ iso}\},\mathcal M=\{f\mid f_L \text{ iso}\}$ form a factorization system?

Comment: Hi Fosco (oh, I see I have revealed your secret name, something weird is going to happen to me like to Valerius Soranus, but anyway...), have you tried using the orthogonality between $D_{\geq 0}$ and $D_{\leq -1}$?

Comment: Dear Eric, the short note Fosco and me were needing the answer to the above question is now ready. We are planning to upload that on the arXiv soon, but a hopefully final version of it is already available here: http://nforum.mathforge.org/discussion/6157/tstructures-and-factorization-systems/

Answer (score 6):

Just to explain Eric's construction in more elementary terms (and to point out that you can get something stronger than in your question). Define $C$ as follows:

$$C_n=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
B_n,&n>0,\\
A_n&n<0.
\end{array}
\right.$$
Moreover, let $d_n\colon C_n\rightarrow C_{n-1}$ be the differential of $B$ (resp. $A$) if $n>1$ (resp. $n<0$). We must still define $C_0$ and its surrounding differentials.

We define $C_0$ as the push-out 
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
Z_0(A)&\rightarrow&Z_0(B)\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
A_0&\rightarrow&C_0
\end{array}$$
The upper arrow is the map induced on $0$-cycles by $f$ and the left arrow is the inclusion of $0$-cycles in $0$-chains, which is injective. Therefore the parallel arrow is also injective. Moreover, $A_0/Z_0(A)=C_0/Z_0(B)$.

The differential $d_0\colon C_0\rightarrow C_{-1}=A_{-1}$ is given by applying the universal property of a push-out to $d_0\colon A_0\rightarrow A_{-1}$ and the trivial map $0\colon Z_0(B)\rightarrow A_{-1}$. This shows that $Z_0(C)=Z_0(B)$ and that the images of $d_0\colon C_0\rightarrow C_{-1}=A_{-1}$ and $d_0\colon A_0\rightarrow A_{-1}$ coincide.

The differential $d_1\colon C_1=B_1\rightarrow C_0$ is the composite $B_1\rightarrow Z_0(B)\hookrightarrow C_0$.

We now take $h\colon A\rightarrow C$ to be $f_n\colon A_n\rightarrow B_n$ for $n>0$, the identity for $n<0$, and the bottom map in the push-out square for $n=0$. The map $g\colon C\rightarrow B$ is the identity for $n>0$, $f_n\colon A_n\rightarrow B_n$ for $n<0$, and for $n=0$, the map induced by applying the universal property of a push-out to $f_0\colon A_0\rightarrow B_0$ and $Z_0(B)\hookrightarrow B_0$.

Clearly $f=gh$. Moreover, $\tau_{\geq 0}g$ and $\tau_{\leq -1}h$ are identity maps, not only weak equivalences, by the previous computations. This construction is actually functorial in $f$.

Comment: I have a similar problem here (see my comment to Eric's answer): now I can define $\mathcal E = \left\{ 
\begin{smallmatrix}
A \\ \downarrow \\ B 
\end{smallmatrix} \mid 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
Z_0 A & \overset{Z_0 f}\to & Z_0 B \\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
A_0 & \underset{f_0}\to & B_0
\end{array} \text{ is a pushout}
\right\}$ and $\mathcal M = \left\{ 
\begin{smallmatrix}
A \\ \downarrow \\ B 
\end{smallmatrix} \mid 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
Z_0 A & \overset{Z_0 f}\to & Z_0 B \\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
A_0 & \underset{\cong}\to & A\amalg_{ Z_0A}Z_0B
\end{array} 
\right\}$. Is it a FS?

Comment: @tetrapharmakon I don't think so, too few conditions.

Comment: Ha! So this doesn't solve the original problem :( (your answer was extremely useful, though)

Comment: Oh. I see now that Domenico phrased the original problem in a form weaker than that we need. In fact we were looking for *factorization systems* on $Ch(R)$, not only for factorization functors (thought as sections of the composition functor $Ch(R)\times Ch(R)\to Ch(R)$)... Can your proof (or Eric's) be adapted to this end?

Comment: @tetrapharmakon I just meant that $\mathcal E$ and $\mathcal M$ are not the appropriate classes of morphisms to consider. More conditions are necessary ($A\rightarrow B$ must induce isomorphisms in negative/positive degrees).

Comment: Maybe the point is that it's not really clear to me to which extent a FS is determined by its rule to factor morphisms (the factorization functor sending $f$ to the composable pair $f_E, f_M$ s.t. $f_Mf_E=f$). I can state a precise question if needed.

Comment: @tetrapharmakon I must acknowledge that I'm not acquainted enough with the notion of factorisation system. Wikipedia says that an equivalent definition is: the functorial factorization (which is what I give above) + an orthogonality condition. I haven't checked the latter, but it looks plausible.

Comment: MathOverflow wants us to avoid long discussions in comments. Maybe we can [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14914/discussion-between-tetrapharmakon-and-fernando-muro)?

Comment: Meanwhile: Joyal gave a powerful alternative characterization which give us orthogonality for free if we show that the two classes are closed under isomorphisms and composition and we have a functorial factorization. Maybe the point is that the right procedure to extract the FS from the functorial factorization is *not* what I said before?