# A factorization system on ${\rm Ch}(R)$

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

This is a sort of follow up to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168699/homotopy-factorization-of-morphisms-of-chain-complexes).

Let $R$ be a ring (eventually with good properties) and $\mathrm{Ch}(R)$ be the category of chain complexes of $R$-modules (eventually bounded).

Following the hint by F. Muro given in [his answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/168873/7952), I would like to know if the following two classes
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal E &= \left\{
\left. f:\begin{array}{c} X\\ \downarrow \\ Y\end{array}\right|
\begin{array}{ccc}
Z_0 X &\to &  Z_0Y \\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
X_0 & \underset{f_0}\to & Y_0
\end{array}
\text{ is a pushout, } f_n \text{ iso }\forall (n<0)
\right\}\\
\mathcal M &= \left\{
\left. g:\begin{array}{c} A\\ \downarrow \\ B\end{array}\right|
\begin{array}{ccc}
Z_0 A &\to &  Z_0B \\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
A_0 & = & A_0
\end{array}
\text{ is a pushout, } g_n \text{ iso }\forall (n>0)
\right\}
\end{align*}
$$
form a [factorization system](http://ncatlab.org/joyalscatlab/published/Factorisation+systems) on $\mathrm{Ch}(R)$, where $Z_0(-)\to (-)_0$ is the inclusion of the 0-cycles.